# Use /etc/aliases for outgoing mail relayed by postfix with local domain

Tags: cron, postfix

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with postfix configured as satellite system that relays outgoing mail to Gmail. For sake of example, my registered domain is example.com I want root cronjobs' error output to be mailed to my real david@example.com inbox. I have this relay working correctly.

But these root cronjobs are set by default to email to root@example.com which isn't a real email address. I have in my `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: david@example.com
```

example.com isn't listed in postfix's main.cf's `mydestination` so postfix doesn't think this mail is local. It bypasses processing via `/etc/aliases` and tries to send to root@example.com.

A workaround is adding `MAILTO=david` at the top of each cron file. But there are many. Another workaround is to setup root@example.com as a real inbox that forwards to david@example.com. Is there a better way? I.e. is there a way to relay emails that have local domains but still process their addressee with `/etc/aliases`?

Comment: Side-note: I would recommend `nullmailer` if you don't need a full-fledged MTA for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the postfix `myorigin` value is set to `example.com`. On Debian (not 100% certain about Ubuntu) that is controlled by default in `/etc/mailname`.

The value of `myorigin` is used as the domain part when messages are prepared. This should be set to something that is in `mydestination`.

If those are set correctly then you'll get the behavior you're expecting from your configured aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `relayhost` - in your case probably the Gmail SMTP server.

This `relayhost` will get any mail not considered local (instead of trying to contact the mailrelay for each domain directly).